# How to make a new page on magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, page

i know that this may be a stupid question, i've done reading MagentoDesignGuide.pdf and knows how to edit block, how the XML layout works, and template files works. Since magento documentation is not much i need a lot of question on the development (i'm new to magento Environment and framework)

what i get is 1 page of magento is made from lots of block, layout and modules. either way i want one of my link in my homepage goes to my custom page (a page which i want to made on my own). is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, you created a CMS page, with `URL Key = introduction`

You can add link of this page (on your CMS homepage) by :

`<a href="{{store url="introduction"}}">Introduction</a>`

For template files (.phtml), use:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('introduction'); ?>">Introduction</a>
```

Comment: how about none cms pages? i thought there're lots of them on every themes

Comment: what's `none cms pages` ?

Comment: CMS page is the easiest way to create a page